# python-sybase transaction silently fails on update

Tags: python, transactions, sybase

We're using python-sybase 0.38 to transactionally execute update statements. We are seeing transactions fail due to deadlock in the Sybase logs, however, the python function call seems to execute without any errors - no exception is thrown (but the row is not updated).

```
syb = Sybase.connect(server, user, password, database, auto_commit = 1)
syb.execute("begin tran")
syb.execute("update ....")
syb.execute("commit tran")
```

(the `begin tran` and `commit tran` statements are not required with `auto_commit`, however this is how the code was provided).

We are seeing failures in perhaps 5% of cases. How do we detect the failure of the `update` statement?

Comment: Have you tried checking `@@error` or using `raiserror` in your update command to check/notify when a transaction doesn't complete?  Also, you may want to determine what's causing the deadlocks to see if you can keep them from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with python-sybase versions up to and including 0.39. From the [release notes](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-December/594274.html):

> MAJOR CHANGES SINCE 0.39:
>
> [snip]
>
> Added new exception DeadLockError when Sybase is in a deadlock situation

We were unable to set up a 0.40 installation to confirm, but the above looks like a likely cause.